# Use ejs instead of pug template in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am just a newbie in `node js` using `node js` with `express framework`. Currently the express framework is using pug template engine. I want to use `ejs` template. So how to do that. My app.js is looking like this

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var admin = require('./routes/admin');


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/admin', admin);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first

```
npm install ejs
```

and then replace

```
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
```

with

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Comment: what would be the file extension for ejs files? .ejs ?

Comment: yes its .ejs this time nad you have to change the code of that file according to ejs using by adding some thing like <%= variablename %>